# How to read a private key from pvk file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, certificate, private-key

I have to read a private key, and this key is on pvk format. I use X509Certificate2 class, but i this class i have only public key access. 
How can I get a private key from pvk file?

Comment: @Luis, I am struggling with the same at the moment. Did you figure out how to get the private key from a .pvk file?

Comment: @RashmiPandit, I forgot completely of checked the correct answer. I just checked. It work's for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luiz, you need to combine the CER and PVK into a single PFX file, then import the file as a cert so that when you load the X509Cert the PrivateKey will be there.  See [Decrypt with PrivateKey X.509 Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097514/decrypt-with-privatekey-x-509-certificate).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey.aspx

How about this ?

Have in mind:

> Currently this property supports only
>   RSA or DSA keys, so it returns either
>   an RSACryptoServiceProvider or a
>   DSACryptoServiceProvider object. If no
>   private key is associated with the
>   certificate, a null reference (Nothing
>   in Visual Basic) is returned

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  The link shows how to read the PrivateKey from an X509Cert if it's already present, but not how to load it from a pvk file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to combine them.

```
pvk2pfx -spc CA.cer -pvk CA.pvk -pfx CA.pfx
```

[Decrypt with PrivateKey X.509 Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097514/decrypt-with-privatekey-x-509-certificate)